# Making appassembler-maven-plugin add sources for dependent artifacts (or find another way to do it)?

Tags: java, maven, appassembler

I am looking into making it easier to debug problems in our Maven deployments, and the appassembler-maven-plugin plugin is very useful for creating a multi-jar deployment where the various jars can be placed in a Maven repository file structure named "repo" (as opposed to a flat directory).  This may make it easy to investigate a problem, by copying the deployment to a developer machine and tell an IDE to use "repo" as an actual (read/only) Maven repository!  (This probably requires some pom.xml magic, but I'll sort that out later)

Now I had the thought that having the exact sources for the deployment as part of the deployment would be very beneficial as it will allow you to work with actual code instead of a disassembly of the byte code.

So the question is:  Given I have such a directory laid out as a Maven repository created by the appassembler, how do I add the necessary files to each jar in it (if present) make it workable with sources (and javadoc too, but that is less important)?